# Getting binary response or method not allowed. When tried setting only http endpoint I never got response its just keeping processing for long time

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using wso2 1.10.0 api manager for first time. I need to access the http backend with simple query parameter. I published the api and tried either by setting as queryparam or json object, it's not giving me the expected result. I will get binary response or method not allowed. When tried setting only http endpoint I never got response its just keeping processing for long time. Please suggest me how do I access simple http backend. Need to show demo in a week.

Please help to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You get 'method not allowed' when you try to access a resource which was not defined for that method (say backend has POST method supporting resource only and you try to do a GET request)

I guess the issue is with the way you have defined the resources for the api from the publisher application. (invalid HTTP methods for resources)

If you think you have defined them correctly, then the next step to identify the issue is wirelogs. wirelogs provide all the info in request passing through the api manager gateway (request headers, body etc)
Follow this article http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/09/wso2-esb-all-about-wire-logs.html on how to enable and read them

You can then directly call the backend (say curl -v to the backend) and compare the request from the direct call vs the one going out from 
gateway to the backend and check the difference. This would help you start finding the issue

Comment: I tried with proper method as POST and set endpoint as AdressEndpoit, then tried sending parameter as query, but still getting the response as  <am:message>Runtime Error</am:message>
  <am:description>Error while building message</am:description>

Comment: Here is my query extract sequence:

Comment: <sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="msisdn-query">    
 <property name="MSISDN" expression="$url:MSISDN"></property><payloadFactory media-type="xml"><format><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body><ns1:APIGEE_getUsageInquiry_RequestMessage xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/ProcessAPIGEEAIARequestor"><ns1:APIGEE_Request>
<ns1:MSISDN>{MSISDN}</ns1:MSISDN></ns1:APIGEE_Request></ns1:APIGEE_getUsageInquiry_RequestMessage></soap:Body></soap:Envelope></format><args>

Comment: <arg xmlns:m0="http://services.samples/xsd" evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('MSISDN')"></arg></args></payloadFactory></sequence>

Comment: Did you enable wirelogs? if so can you share the whole log (paste it in your question or somewhere else). Another thing I notice is {MSISDN} inside the <MSISDN> tag. you cannot add anything you want in the payload factory mediator. set it to $1 . that is how params are set for payload factory. see 'Example 1: XML' in https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/PayloadFactory+Mediator. I think you are getting an error message from the backend because of this and that msg cannot be parsed from AM.

Comment: Hi Chamila, I am not finding the expected result...the link to configure wirelogs is not opening. my backend accepts only "http" requests. i have tried with following IN sequence;

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="sample-property"><payloadFactory media-type="xml" description=""><format><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns1:APIGEE_getUsageInquiry_RequestMessage xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/ProcessAPIGEEAIARequestor"><ns1:APIGEE_Request><ns1:MSISDN>$1</ns1:MSISDN></ns1:APIGEE_Request></ns1:APIGEE_getUsageInquiry_RequestMessage></soap:Body></soap:Envelope></format><args/></payloadFactory>

Comment: <property name="MSISDN" expression="get-property('MSISDN')" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/></sequence>

Comment: My requirement is very simple..i need to need extract the value of MSISDN which is sent as query param from Android app and build the SOAP payload and send to backend. Then response received from backend is converted to json. This have tried in apigee, its very easy. But for the first time i am trying with WSO2 AM, please suggest me any modifications need to be done . NOTE: the backend accepts http request only. When i tried configuring only http endpoint in wso2 by changing the gateway endpoints to only http in api-manager.xml and commenting the line HostnameVerifier in transportsender

Comment: in axis2.xml. when i do like this, i will never get response, it be just process

Comment: Enabling wire logs
1. open log4j.properties file from a text editor.
log4j.properties file is located in /repository/conf directory.
2. Un-comment the following entry. 
log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG  3. restart and do a request. Without looking at the wirelogs it is bit difficult to find the reason

Comment: When u mean backend i assume it is the web service. if so, you dont have to change anything in api-manager.xml. gateway endpoints are there to configure when apim is in a cluster. for your case you can do your thing without configuring anything.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to API manager, I would recommend you to do following first

1. Try out a simple scenario similar to your one. You can google it. This is from official documentation. would recommend to try out a simple scenario first. say https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Convert+a+JSON+Message+to+SOAP+and+SOAP+to+JSON
2. Then use SOAP UI or similar app to directly call the backend web service (not the api manager) and get the SOAP request and SOAP response for the backend.
3. Then create the api in API manager. you need to do the same thing in the sample i provided. only difference is the soap payload. use the previously collected SOAP messages.
4. Enable wire logs. for that see the comments in the previous answer. In wirelogs you will see >> and << signs

   To read the wire log, first we have to identify message direction.

DEBUG - wire >>    -  This represent the message coming into API manager from the wire (will notice two set of these. one coming in to the
gateway from the rest client and response coming in to the api manager from the backend. )

DEBUG - wire <<    -  This represents the message going to the wire from API manager (again two sets. request going from api manager to the
backend service and the response sent to the rest client from the api manager.)

the soap message will be printed in this log. check for the request going from api manager to the backend and the response coming from the
backend to the api manager. you can compare that to the onces you collected in the step 2 and do modifications if needed to the sequnces.
the wirelogs will also print the http headers. so check that as well.

hope you could set up a working sample using these steps

Comment: Hi Chamila, thanks. I am able to get the expected response now. I had tried that example before but was trying with Queryparameter. Here in the present need to send json object as payload but i wanted to send only the value of parameter as query param and build soap message. Anyway for time being it has resolved the issue. Thanks again!

Comment: Does wso2 1.10.0 API manager supports windows server 2008 R2 enterprise OS?

Comment: glad you got that resolved. regarding OS, we have tested AM 1.10 on windows environment (not specifically on windows server but it should work.) You only need java home set to run on windows.  There could be some issues if you use older versions of Internet explorer to access publisher and store (swagger stuff)